# How to check if Jar is running on windows and run the logs?

Tags: java, windows, jar, javaw

I have a jar that I'm running on a windows server that I ran using `java -jar filename.jar`  and i closed the terminal window. I then ran the other jar using the command `javaw -jar filename.jar` and closed the terminal window also.

I would like to check if both of them are running and if possible see the logs on the terminal.

I have tried running the command `wmic process where "name like '%java%'" get commandline,processid` but i do not understand the result.

Comment: Normally, when you close a terminal, its child processes will be closed too. You can easily check in task manager if your processes are still running.

Comment: thanks but the jar that i ran using `javaw` should be running in the background and the task manager only shows there are jars running but the names are generic, you don't know which jar is which.  Is there a way of knowing which jar is which and can i open the instance and start seeing logs on the terminal?

Comment: You can display the "command line" column in task manager. It should show you the exact command that was used to start the process. It will contain your JAR's name.

Comment: Thank you that really helped. Can i open the jars that are running?